# What hook_form_alter code do I need to change an exposed filter from a text field to a select box search?

Tags: javascript, theming, views

I have a view that has an age to and and from fields, and others also that I want TO and FROM.

These are integer fields, so drop down select doesn't work, better exposed filters is also not an option.

What CSS, or Java script can I put in the Hook_form_alter to make this work?

Website that has the form is [www.vuxi.com](http://www.vuxi.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to go for specific implementation using hook alter this would be great option.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $view = $form_state['view'];
    if ($view->name == 'my_view_machine_name' && $view->current_display == 'display_name') {
      // alter your exposed form here
      $addition[$field_name] = array(
        '#attributes' => array(
          'class' => array(
            // you can define you class overhere
          ),
        ),
      ),
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change textfield to select box using following code

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "your view name"  ){
    $options = array('your options');
    $form['your field name']['#type'] ='select';
    $form['your field name']['#size'] = null;
    $form['your field name']['#default_value'] = '';
    $form['your field name']['#options'] = $options;
  }
}
```

Change the field attributes as your field attributes.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: the above will help you. you ca define your own drop down list using form alter and for displaying the result. you can use views query alter for desired result.

Comment: Ok, it kind of work, but getting errors, and loosing the first basic block...code is `<?php
       

function dropdowninteger_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "views_exposed_form"  )
  {
    $options = array('45', '46');
 $form['field_user_age_value']['#type'] ='select';
    $form['field_user_age_value']['#size'] = null;
    $form['field_user_age_value']['#default_value'] = '';
    $form['field_user_age_value']['#options'] = $options;
  }
   
  
}

?>
  ` and an error"An illegal choice has been detected...."

Comment: use    **if($form_id == "view id" && $form['#id']=='current view display' )**  and use options array as **array(key => value)** format..

Comment: Thanks Abin, but not quite there yet! what should I put [EXACTLY] into array(key => value)  , I tried many combinations and I can't get it working, like array(1=>1) , array("1"=>1) , array("1"=>$1) .... I have no idea about PHP...drop down is for ages 18-99

Comment: '<?php
       
    function dropdowninteger_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id']=='current view display' ){
    $options = array(key => value);
    $form['field_user_age_value']['#type'] ='select';
    $form['field_user_age_value']['#size'] = null;
    $form['field_user_age_value']['#default_value'] = '';
    $form['field_user_age_value']['#options'] = $options;
  }
} '

Comment: you can use  `$options = array('1' => '1', '2'=>'2', ...)` or you can use a function to generate values. 'function age(){for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){$options[$i] = $i;}return $options;}

Comment: Hi Abin, I have put this code in and it works: '<?php function dropdowninteger_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
 { if($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id']=='views-exposed-form-hide-tweaked-advanced' )
 {$options = array('1' => '1', '2'=>'2');
 $form['field_user_age_value']['#type'] ='select';
  $form['field_user_age_value']['#size'] = null;
   $form['field_user_age_value']['#default_value'] = '';
    $form['field_user_age_value']['#options'] = $options; 
 } 
 } ' However...I still get this error: An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.

Comment: @BrunoVincent in which file and which line the error indicating..??

Comment: Hi Abin, there is no line that the error indicates to. It's just an error in a red box on top. If I publish that site online on  a test URL, can you login and look inside, I can also give you the FTP login to si you can look at the module, but the code is what I pasted on top

Comment: @BrunoVincent I think the reason for this error is related with the values of **$option**. You have to replace with original values in your field.

Comment: You mean on this line:  $form['field_user_age_value']['#options'] = $options; ? This site is crashed now, so I can't test this evening...

Comment: @BrunoVincent Ok Bruno.. The problem may be $options = array('1' => '1', '2'=>'2'); you have to replace the **key**  in **key=>value** with your original values.